# Underscore parameter for ping and negotiate

Tags: javascript, url, signalr, performance-testing

Where is the underscore parameter generated from on SignalR URLs?

e.g. the XHR GETs to `/signalr/negotiate?_=1234561234` and `/signalr/ping?_=789012341234`

It doesn't appear to be passed from the server so I am wondering if it is a purely client side generated value?

I am asking as am I attempted to write a script to performance test the application but I do not know what to use for these parameter values. I guessed that this might be randomly generated but I wish to confirm or disconfirm this. Usually these are based on time, but they don't seem to be the usual UNIX epoch time format.

Please answer with specific reference to SignalR and if possible the code snippet where this is generated.

Comment: Looks like the typical random suffix to avoid caching - in that case it's randomly generated at client side, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Most libraries when provided a no caching flag use _ as a key to suffix random query parameter to avoid url caching.
e.g if in jQuery, you do  $ajaxSetup -> cache:false, then a key `_` with value equal to current timestamp gets appended in every url call.
So yes, this is most probably client side addition.